# Converting csr_sparse matrix to dense Matrix blows up the memory

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, naivebayes

the problem is

```
classifier_np = GaussianNB()
classifier_np.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

gives the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_23/2974247449.py in <module>
      1 classifier_np = GaussianNB()
----> 2 classifier_np.fit(X_train, y_train)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    244         y = self._validate_data(y=y)
    245         return self._partial_fit(
--> 246             X, y, np.unique(y), _refit=True, sample_weight=sample_weight
    247         )
    248 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in _partial_fit(self, X, y, classes, _refit, sample_weight)
    400 
    401         first_call = _check_partial_fit_first_call(self, classes)
--> 402         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, reset=first_call)
    403         if sample_weight is not None:
    404             sample_weight = _check_sample_weight(sample_weight, X)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    579                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    580             else:
--> 581                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    582             out = X, y
    583 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    974         ensure_min_samples=ensure_min_samples,
    975         ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
--> 976         estimator=estimator,
    977     )
    978 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    724             copy=copy,
    725             force_all_finite=force_all_finite,
--> 726             accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
    727         )
    728     else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _ensure_sparse_format(spmatrix, accept_sparse, dtype, copy, force_all_finite, accept_large_sparse)
    439     if accept_sparse is False:
    440         raise TypeError(
--> 441             "A sparse matrix was passed, but dense "
    442             "data is required. Use X.toarray() to "
    443             "convert to a dense numpy array."

TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

So I did

X_train.toarray()

and that blows up the memory any answers to how to prevent this or fix this will really help.

Also I am pretty new to machine learning and couldn't find any answers for this on google

As I explained in question I did X.toarray() that didn't work out, is there an better way to this?

Comment: Your `X_train` is too large (shape wise) for this.

Comment: `GaussianNB` implements partial fit. Break `X_train` and `y_train` up by selecting a subset of rows, converting them to dense, and then feeding them into `classifier_np.partial_fit()`. Do this until you have fit the entire dataset.